# Apache solr bad json response?

Tags: json, solr

I'm making the following request:

> GET /solr/populationvars8/select?q=pob&wt=json&json.wrf=jQuery191039282788056880236_1370268228739&rows=2&hl=true&hl.fl=description_autocomplete&_=1370268228740 HTTP/1.1

The response is meant to be rendered through jquery autocomplete. The problem is that the "highlighting" data is being returned incorrectly (or so I think). Here is part of my response:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 29
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 491,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [
            {
                "description": "Población de 70 años y más",
                "description_autocomplete": "Población de 70 años y más",
                "accesibilidad": "y"
            },
            {
                "description": "Población de 65 años y más",
                "description_autocomplete": "Población de 65 años y más",
                "accesibilidad": "y"
            }
        ]
    },
    "highlighting": {
        "": {
            "description_autocomplete": [
                "Población de 65 años y más"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the "highlighting" response has some bad key/value pairs (duplicate key name because it's blank). The result is that when this JSON is parsed I always get the last "description_autocomplete" data. If you want to see what the actual result is, you can copy-paste JSON code into jsonlint.com and it will say its valid but it will only have one "highlighting" result.

Am I missing something in my solr config or is this some minor bug in solr?

Notes:

- schema.xml has "unikeKey" tag (not really sure if this will help)
- field "description_autocomplete" is a "copyField" from another field.
- above request when done through browser gives full json, but when parsed (choose your tool) I only get one "highlighting" result
- I know that in RFC 4627 (JSON specification) this doesn't seem to be valid json
- if needed I can provide my solr config
- solr version is 4.3.0 1477023

Comment: It seems the unique is missing in your case, thats why the id is not displayed for the highlighting section which will enable you to map it to the response? Do you populate the unique key and it is marked required ?

Comment: indeed thats what i was missing, unique wasnt being populated.
thanks jayendra.

Comment: cool ... I can add it as an answer and you accept it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting sections can be matched to the respective response with the unique id.

It seems the unique is missing in your case, that's why the id is not displayed for the highlighting section which will enable you to map it to the response.

Do you populate the unique key and it is marked required ?